# 'Where' clause with graphite queries

Tags: mapreduce, graphite, bigdata

I hold a lot of time-series metric data in graphite. Let's assume I have 2 different metrics **X** and **Y** that represent the prices of two different products.

I would now like to query the data from an app and do something like this (of course, that's a pseudo-sql):

```
Select all points of metric X where value is smaller than value of metric Y during a time frame
```

I couldn't find any reasonable way, without writing my own script or some map-reduce job, to do it.

I could, for example, plot the graphs and try to understand it visually pretty easily. But it won't be usable for an app to use.

I also thought about using some functions like `currentBelow` and `currentAbove` but it doesn't look like I can provide two different series to compare but only one specific integer per the entire period of time.

Comment: Isn't retrieving both metrics and comparing them in your script feasible? @kwarunek solution below looks right, but I don't know if its "complexity" pays off, or even if it is faster than doing the calculations manually in your script.

Comment: @dukebody - That's exactly what I'm wondering. I'm trying to figure out whether there's a way, which I don't fully understand, to query graphite for such complex query instead of writing scripts. If not, I'll see what better pays off - script of the answer provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I hope there is some better solution ;).

The solution is:

Metrics:

```
product.X.price
product.Y.price
```

1. create a filter mask - values 0 is not greater, 1 is greater

   1. [diffSeries](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.diffSeries) - to set bound 0 - above points we want to include, below to exclude.

      ```
      diffSeries(product.X.price, product.Y.price)
      ```
   2. [removeBelowValue](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.removeBelowValue) - to remove all excluded - below 0,

      ```
      removeBelowValue(diffSeries(product.X.price, product.Y.price), 0)
      ```
   3. [divideSeries](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.divideSeries) - divide above series by itself to create a mask of 0 and 1 - fortunately in graphite's functions 0/0 = 0 (sic!),

      ```
      divideSeries(removeBelowValue(diffSeries(product.X.price, product.Y.price), 0), removeBelowValue(diffSeries(product.X.price, product.Y.price), 0))
      ```
2. filter out using prepared mask with [multiplySeries](http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/functions.html#graphite.render.functions.multiplySeries), since

   0 * datapoint = 0

   1 * datapoint = datapoint

   ```
   multiplySeries(product.X.price, divideSeries(removeBelowValue(diffSeries(product.X.price, product.Y.price), 0), removeBelowValue(diffSeries(product.X.price, product.Y.price), 0)))
   ```

Comment: I also hope there's a better solution but I tried to think how to figure this out from existing functions using Graphite and what you did looks awesome! If there's no better solution, I'm happy to see it's solvable. I still need to get the details figured out for myself to make sure it works, and also wait a little and see whether a simpler solution arrives. So I'll accept the answer in 2-3 days. Thank you in any case!